# The group of global sections of the automorphism bundle of the tangent bundle on a Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fibre-bundles, grassmannians, line-bundles

Let $X={\rm Gr}(k,n)$ denote the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces in ${\Bbb C}^n$.
We regard $X$ as an algebraic variety over $\Bbb C$.
Let ${T_X} \to X$ denote the tangent bundle on $X$. For an explicit description of ${T_X}$ see e.g.
[here](https://concretenonsense.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/tangent-bundle-of-the-grassmannian/).
Consider the induced bundle ${\rm GL}({T_X})\to X$ whose fiber at $x\in X$ is the automorphism group ${\rm GL}(T_x)$ of the vector space $T_x$.

> **Question 1.** *What is the group $A={\rm Aut}_X\,{T_X}$ of regular global sections of ${\rm GL}({T_X})$ over $X$?*

For any $\lambda \in{\Bbb C}^\times$ we have a global section of ${\rm GL}({T_X})$ taking value $\lambda I_x$ at $x$, where $I_x$ is the identity automorphism of $T_x$.
Thus we obtain a canonical embedding ${\Bbb C}^\times\hookrightarrow A$.

> **Question 2.** *Is it true that $A={\Bbb C}^\times\,$?*
>
> **Question 3.**  *In particular, is the answer to Question 2 "Yes" for $X={\rm Gr}(1,n+1)={\Bbb P}^n\,$?*

I know that the answer to Question 2 is  "Yes" for $X={\rm Gr}(1,2)={\Bbb P}^1$.
In this case ${\rm GL}({T_X})={\Bbb C}^\times\times {\Bbb P}^1\to {\Bbb P}^1$.

Comment: The situation is completely uniform, and what happens for $\mathbb{P}^1$ happens for all $G/P$ (at least in type ADE), see Boralevi: On simplicity and stability of the tangent bundle of rational homogeneous varieties (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3202710). So $A=\mathbb{C}^\times$ for all Grassmannians.

Comment: @pbelmans: Excellent! Many thanks! Later I was going to ask a question about the tangent bundle of $G/P$ ...

Comment: I state here the relevant result of Ada Boralevi. Let $G$ be a simple algebraic group over $\Bbb C$ of one of the types ADE, and let $P\subset G$ be a parabolic subgroup. Set $X=G/P$. Then the tangent bundle $T_X$ of $X$ is simple, that is, ${\rm End}_X\,T_X={\Bbb C}$. This answers in the positive my Questions 2 and 3. See [Ada Boralevi,  On simplicity and stability of the tangent bundle of rational homogeneous varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2350), Theorem 4.4.